# Error On Delete Google Sheet Table Content Based On A Value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to delete all table contents in Google Sheet when a value in cell F1 is "DELETE", the table content starts in row 3. I tried this code in the script but it didn't work:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var r = s.getRange("F1");
  var v = r.getValues();
  if (v == "DELETE") s.deleteRow(3, s.getLastRow());
}
```

Your response will be appreciated.
​​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are 2 modification points in yuor script.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, please use `deleteRows` instead of `deleteRow`.
- When `s.deleteRow(3, s.getLastRow())` is used, when the last row is the lowest row in the sheet, an error occurs. So in this case, please use `s.deleteRows(3, s.getLastRow() - 2);`

#### Modified script:

From:

```
s.deleteRow(3, s.getLastRow());
```

To:

```
s.deleteRows(3, s.getLastRow() - 2);
```

#### References:

- [deleteRow(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition)
- [deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany)

Comment: @Ray Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.